# Install signed ServiceStack assemblies from Package Manager Console

Tags: servicestack, nuget, nuget-package

I need ServiceStack signed assemblies to deploy them into GAC.

How can I install signed assemblies from Package Manager Console?

I tried this command but the package is not found:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Signed
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'ServiceStack.Signed'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package ServiceStack.Signed
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Signed packages of ServiceStack are only available in v4, which at the moment is only available for evaluation [on MyGet at these instructions](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/NxHUpV1sg1d), until v4-beta is released.

v4-beta is expected to be available on NuGet at the end of this month (Nov 2013).

Comment: Does V4 need .NET 4 ?